# Type hinting return value with ^ or :tag meta?

Tags: clojure, type-hinting

The two seem to be doing the same thing in Clojure. Which syntax is canonical?

```
(defn a ^int [] 4)

(defn b ^{:tag int} [] 4)
```

I hope it's `a` since it's shorter.

Comment: Actually, type-hinting a function to int doesn't work anymore. it's all long and doubles. And there's all possible combinations added here: https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/IFn.java#L97 And it's not as crazy as it seems.

Comment: @claj Dear god, I hope that code was generated somehow. Otherwise, I feel sorry for whichever poor sap got stuck with that job.

Comment: Probably a combination of https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics and https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.pprint/cl-format

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I only use `b` when I need to include metadata other than just the tag. For example, when implementing a transient collection, I needed

```
(deftype Whatever [^{:tag ITransientVector
                     :unsynchronized-mutable true} foo])
```

Note that it would be equivalent and perfectly acceptable to write

```
(deftype Whatever [^:unsynchronized-mutable ^ITransientVector foo])
```

but I personally prefer the explicit map.

Answer (score 5):

Its 'a' that is canonical. Its the only one I have seen so far in Clojure code and in the documentation on the Clojure site. See **[here](http://clojure.org/java_interop#Java%20Interop-Type%20Hints)** for more information on type hints.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'd be pretty surprised if there's a speed difference. It *might* compile a hair faster, but it should run the same, and compilation only happens once. Do you have the benchmark handy that you used to test this?

Comment: +1 Your right, tested again and the time taken varied for me but they look both are similar so probably no speed increase. Post edited accordingly.

Comment: +1. Also worth noting that (a) is actually just syntactic sugar for (b) so they produce the same results at runtime.

Comment: +1 Thanks for clearing that up mikera. I thought both were equivalent but couldn't find any confirmation of it.